# Как программно поменять цвет у курсора в SearchView?

Tags: android, android-search-view

Как программно поменять цвет у курсора в SearchView?

Answer (score 0):

drawable/cursor.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#31ff03" />//
    <size android:width="2dp" />
</shape>
```

Код

```
    SearchManager manager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(manager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    int textViewID = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text",null, null);

    AutoCompleteTextView searchTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(textViewID);
    try {
        Field mCursorDrawableRes = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
        mCursorDrawableRes.setAccessible(true);
        mCursorDrawableRes.set(searchTextView, R.drawable.cursor); 
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```